# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermissio

Tags: java, android

I am following one tutorial upload video from android to server on this [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-video-to-server-using-php/) . But when i execute this activity it gave me run time exception. According to the exception I have added permissions in the `manifest` file. But still getting the error. Here is my activity file

```
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button buttonChoose;
    private Button buttonUpload;
    private TextView textView;
    private TextView textViewResponse;
    private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 3;
    private String selectedPath;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        report = getIntent().getStringExtra("report");
        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textViewResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResponse);
        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void chooseVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a Video "), SELECT_VIDEO);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
                System.out.println("SELECT_VIDEO");
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                textView.setText(selectedPath);
            }
        }
    }
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }

    private void uploadVideo() {
        class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog uploading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                uploading = ProgressDialog.show(UploadActivity.this, "Uploading File", "Please wait...", false, false);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                uploading.dismiss();
                textViewResponse.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Uploaded at <a href='" + s + "'>" + s + "</a></b>"));
                textViewResponse.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                UploadFile u = new UploadFile();
                String msg = u.uploadVideo(selectedPath);
                return msg;
            }
        }
        UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo();
        uv.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            chooseVideo();
        }
        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            uploadVideo();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat

```
03-16 09:00:28.658 5832-5832/com.example.luke.upload E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.luke.upload, PID: 5832
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:21079 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.luke.upload/com.example.luke.upload.UploadActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/video/media from pid=5832, uid=10234 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4998)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/video/media from pid=5832, uid=10234 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:445)
at com.example.luke.upload.UploadActivity.getPath(UploadActivity.java:63)
at com.example.luke.upload.UploadActivity.onActivityResult(UploadActivity.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7165)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4994)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I am testing it on marshmallow
Thank you.

Comment: android 6 > , you need to request the user for a permission first.. look here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I was looking for run time permissions but where and how should i assign READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    private static final int REQUEST_STORAGE = 112;

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_STORAGE );
                } else {
                      chooseVideo();
                }
            } else {
                chooseVideo();
            }
        }
        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            uploadVideo();
        }
    }
```

get Permissions Result

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   chooseVideo();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I was looking for run time permissions but where should i assign READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission ?

Comment: in `onCreate()`.. checking first either permission is allow or not..

Comment: I am getting error on !hasPermission and mContext. What are these variables ?

Comment: mContext is your current activity context...YourActivity.this